# Mysql - Find duplicates records evaluating 2 columns

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a mysql table with a structure like this:
order_id - customer_name - customer_email_address

i need to do a query to search for records that have same customer_name OR same customer_email and show the result ordered by order_id groups (descending order).

Example:

Mysql table

```
order_id    customer_name    customer_email_address
1           pippo            pippo@pippo.com
2           pippo            pippo2@pippo2.com
3           pluto            pluto@pluto.com
4           caio             pippo@pippo.com
5           pippo4           pippo4@pippo4.com
6           pluto            pluto22@pluto22.com
```

Result

```
6           pluto            pluto22@pluto22.com
3           pluto            pluto@pluto.com
4           caio             pippo@pippo.com     
1           pippo            pippo@pippo.com
2           pippo            pippo2@pippo2.com
```

Result 6 and 3 share the same customer_name
Result 4 and 1 share the same customer_email_address
Result 1 and 2 share the same customer_name

Order_id 5 is not in results because it has no duplicates.

Comment: what you mean 'the result ordered by order_id groups (descending order)'. I don't understand order of your result, why 3 is not first and 6 not second

Comment: @Pottillo I've updated the query because the first time i misunderstood the requirements

Comment: @Justin because i need results from the biggest to the lowest order number. So: given a number of "groups of duplicates", the first to appear should by the order with the higher order number, followed by all the reletive duplicates...and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    customer_name,
    customer_email_address
FROM 
    my_table
WHERE 
    order_id IN (
        SELECT
            order_id
        FROM
            my_table
        GROUP BY
            customer_name
        HAVING 
            COUNT(*)>1

        UNION

        SELECT
            order_id,
        FROM
            my_table
        GROUP BY
            customer_email_address
        HAVING 
            COUNT(*)>1
    )
ORDER BY 
    customer_name,
    customer_email_address,
    order_id DESC
```